# Studying / learning method for physics major

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm currently a third year (BSc.) physics major.

My learning method has always been to rewrite my notes and redo the exercises. I do that because my handwriting becomes pretty bad when the lecture goes too fast so that my notes are not very readable or at least you cannot really study from it. Therefore, it allows me to understand the material as I rewrite my notes, to complete them, structure them and simply having clean notes.

Up to the last year, it was what worked for me. However, if I had a "syllabus" sometimes I could directly study in it.

The problem is that it is really time-consuming to rewrite all these notes for each lecture and this year it becomes unmanageable.

I struggle a lot with my courses (QMII, E&M2 (Jackson), GRE, ...) that it takes so much times to rewrite my notes so that I do not find time to really study the material or do enough exercises. A lot of problem sets are left undone or incomplete.

Since some weeks, I came to the conclusion that this learning method is not a good one for me anymore.

As I was thinking about that, I thought about what the ideal study method would be **if every teacher provided lecture-notes**:

- At the end of the day, study the material we saw the day in the syllabus, make sure I understand everything.
- I would have more time to review the courses at the end of the week for example.
- I would have more time to do exercises which are really important in physics.

However, most of the lecturers do not provide lecture-notes (syllabi) and as I mentioned above, I cannot stick with my notes.

So, I was wondering if you would have some learning tips / method for a physics major ?

P.S.: I'm a visual learner, that's why I leverage the rewriting of my notes to structure them and to use colours so that I can look up the important information faster.

Comment: Rewriting notes seems like an excessively slow way of doing it. You should be reviewing them and asking yourself conceptual questions, reading up on things you're not sure about, and trying new problems -- not simply repeating something you already did.

Comment: Also, I don't recommend following lectures word by word, especially if they're unclear. Textbooks are generally much easier to learn from, given the same time invested.

Comment: As an undergraduate I, too, would take notes in the lectures and rewrite them that evening (or within a day or two), with the textbooks to hand, filling in the gaps and reinforcing the message, helping get stuff from short term memory to long term memory and getting ideas into my own language. It worked!  Stick with it. Lectures are not about memorising facts but about seeing the world in new ways and that is soimething you have to do for yourself, not from anyone else's worldview.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I read a book (might have been *Thinking, Fast and Slow* by Daniel Kahnemann) in which it was stated that the much better way to follow a lecture is to actually read the lecture notes before the lecture takes place and then to just pay attention during the lecture (and of course to ask questions).

The worst method according to this book was actually to copy the professors' notes. Even just listening to the lecture without taking notes was more efficient than copying.

This entire statement was done for lectures in which there are lecture notes provided by the professor. Based on my personal experience, I can totally confirm this and I would also recommend it to you

Addendum: Even if no lecture notes are provided, most of the lectures that I have attended were pretty close to a book that was in most of the cases recommended by the professor at the beginning of the semester.

Comment: +1 for "even just listening to the lecture without taking notes was more efficient than copying". Have never ever found that an efficient use of time in lectures.